# How to debug a third party app on iOS that is not responding?

Tags: ios, debugging

I have an iOS app that freezes after a while. I don't own the app and I don't have the source code. How can I take a spindump like I know it from Mac applications (or something similar) of that app in order to give the developer some hints on where to look for the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> some hints on where to look for the issue

Jailbroken iOS Device, LLDB debugger, plus third-party assistance tools.

Few articles as a starting point:

- [A Guide to Debug Other Developers’ Apps](https://blog.securityevaluators.com/debugging-ios-applications-a-guide-to-debug-other-developers-apps-c041311498eb)
- [The missing guide to debug third party apps on iOS 12](https://medium.com/@felipejfc/the-ultimate-guide-for-live-debugging-apps-on-jailbroken-ios-12-4c5b48adf2fb)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there is a way without using a jailbroken iOS device. Hmm.